# I'm on Windows Vista, and Network does not show other computers or file shares

Tags: windows-vista

I'm on windows vista, and for some reason my network most often doesn't show any other computers or file shares, the other computers in the office do just fine, occasionally it works after restart, but not a lot. Any ideas?

Comment: Is **Network discovery** and **File sharing** turned on? Are the other computers on a different domain? Are the other computers Vista as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough our network was connecting to a linksys but using a crazy long random name. I disconnected the connection and may of even removed it and then connected to the proper linksys.